# How exactly am I accessing the host/server through localhost on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

---

I am working on a school project in which I have to upload data onto a database hosted on phpMyAdmin.

What's confusing me right now is that I see "localhost" at the top of the page and before I even query the database I see "Run SQL query/queries on server "localhost":"

Does this mean that I'm hosting a server on my computer and accessing the database through that? Because then I query for "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';" and it returns with hostname = webhost330. (It is hosted on webhost330.asu.edu).

I'm extremely confused about what this means. Thanks for any possible help.

I'm very new to databases so forgive me if I'm missing something simple here.

EDIT: To clarify: I'm not at school, I'm at my house. What kind of implications does this have? In other words, what's the difference between this and hosting a database locally?

When I host a database on my computer through the MySQL command line client, I can create database information and it's stored on my computer in files. Does this mean that it's initially stored on localhost and then that data is used to create files on my computer?

And then the equivalent of that for the webhost330 is that the localhost stores the database initially but then uploads it to the host at phpMyAdmin? That is the primary thing I'm confused about.

Comment: This exactly means what you assumed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exactly means what you assumed. When connected to `localhost`, you are connected to local MySQL server on same machine. Using `webhost330....` you are connected to that remote MySQL server instance, if that is not the name of your own machine. Your own server can be `webhost30.etcetc`.

**Edit**

If your website is hosted here: `webhost330.asu.edu` then MySQL host either being `webhost330.asu.edu` or `localhost` both mean the same ***local*** MySQL server on your very machine.

**Edit based on your update**

If you are at home, then `localhost` means you are connected to a MySQL server that you have installed on your own computer. and `webhost30.etc.etc` means you are connected to the database you have at your school. Database do allow remote connectivity and if you are connected to school from home, that's a remote MySQL connection.

To remove your confusion, you should use only `localhost` in your code. `localhost` at home will mean the development server which is your home computer, and when you take the same code to `webhost30.etc.etc` then `localhost` for that server will mean its own MySQL installation. So `localhost` will work everywhere as long as you don't want your code to connect to a remote external MySQL database server.

Comment: Sorry to post this twice but I want to make sure you see it:

I'm at my house. What's the difference between this and hosting a database locally?

When I host a database on my computer through the MySQL command line client, I create database information and it's stored on my computer in files. Does this mean that it's initially stored on localhost and that data is used to create files on my computer?

Then the equivalent of that for the webhost330 is the localhost stores the database initially then uploads it to the host later?

Comment: So when I load an .sql file onto the database at webhost330.xxx.xxx/myPhpAdmin I'm connecting to a remote external MySQL database server? Or not? That is basically the source of my confusion. Sorry for not saying it that way earlier.

And is uploading an .sql file onto the database the same as using the "Run SQL query/queries on server "localhost":" interface on myPhpAdmin? Like if I have an .sql file that creates a table, could I effectively do the same thing through multiple statements that would resemble an .sql file but would really just be through the gui provided on myPhpAdmin?

Comment: And if accessing the myPhpAdmin databases form my house is remotely accessing it, then why does it say "...on server "localhost":"?

In other words, is localhost ALWAYS used as a medium in altering databases? It's just not the endpoint in remotely accessed queries?

So locally accessing:  My computer -> localhost -> My computer?
And remotely accessing: My computer -> localhost -> database server?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're at school, and assuming you're on your school network. Then yes, your machine is probably "webhost330.asu.edu". At the very least webhost330.asu.edu thinks "webhost330.asu.edu" is localhost.

Answer (score 1):

To see what "localhost" refers to in terms of MySQL server, you have to look at the URL you are using to connect to the web server.

For example, if the URL is

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

and this instance of phpMyAdmin tells me that the MySQL server is on localhost, this means that the MySQL server is on my local workstation.

If the URL is http://example.com/phpmyadmin, then localhost will mean that the MySQL server is on the same machine (example.com).